# WP: How to change the phone number based on location

Tags: php, wordpress, geolocation, location, ip-geolocation

I am currently finishing the website for my client and the only feature and I can't implement is to show the right phone number to a user based on the location.

I tried to find some plugins but no success. Maybe someone can help me with the piece of code I can implement this feature? Thanks!

Comment: What phone number, what location, what code do you have? Your question is lacking all the details that is important here on SO.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things.

Since geolocation can be spoofed, ideally you would display all available numbers and have a main number. Or even better have call tracking numbers that are changed via script based on visitor acquisition and referral source.

Barring all of that, you can use a resource like <kbd>[ipstack](https://ipstack.com/)</kbd>

You make a request to `https://api.ipstack.com/` with the IP Address you want to use ( potentially `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']`?) and your access key. So your request URL would like like the following:

```
$ipstack_url = 'https://api.ipstack.com/123.456.789.001?access_key=YOURACCESSKEYHERE'
```

WordPress has a built in remote URL function [`wp_remote_get()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) that you can use to get this value.

```
$geo_info = wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $ipstack_url ) );
```

To be nice to ipstack (and your request limit), you should probably cache this with the <kbd>[WP_Transients](https://codex.wordpress.org/Transients_API)</kbd> API for at least 24 hours (these results won't change much, so you could cache even longer if you want). You get 10k requests a month for free, so if you have a high traffic site, this is even more important

Now you can do what you want with the ipstack request for that IP address, like display a different phone number based on the current city.

If we combine all of that, you get something like this:

```
// Get your IP however you want
$ip_addr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

// You'll need an API Key
$api_key = 'YOURACCESSKEYHERE';

// Build your API URL
$api_url = "https://api.ipstack.com/$ip_addr?access_key=$api_key"; // Build the API Url

// Give your transient a unique, yet identifiable name
$transient_name = "ipstack-$ip_addr";

// Check for our transient, if it's not there set it for 24 hours
if( false === ( $transient = get_transient( $transient_name ) ) ){
    set_transient( $transient_name, wp_remote_retrieve_body( wp_remote_get( $api_url ) ), 86400 );
}

// Decode the JSON response we got
$json = json_decode( get_transient( $transient_name ) );

// Do whatever you want with it
if( $json->city == 'Los Angeles' ){
    echo 'Phone For LA: 123-456-7890';
} else if( $json->city == 'San Francisco' ){
    echo 'Phone For SF: 321-654-0987';
} else {
    echo 'Default Phone: 098-765-4321';
}
```